# Round edge where multiple faces exists

Tags: faces, edges, bevel

I've created a sample with a basic cube so I can explain it better, I'd like to smooth/bevel/round an edge  but in one side I've more than one face.
On the left you can see my basic cube, on the right side this is what I got when I bevel it
[image: multiple faces]

As you can see when you have multiple faces bevel is applied accordingly, what I really want is something like what you can see in the picture below:

[image: right one]

When you have just one face the bevel is applied to the edge (because you just have one edge...)
Is there a way to "*round*" the edge (this is what I really want) without worrying to much about "subfaces" in my biggest one ? I have a polygon face with lots of "blender faces" in it.

Answer (score 0):

I come from Lightwave3D and modo, so not that experienced with Blender, but I have tried everything and I just keep getting the same results as you. It looks to me like a limitation of the built-in edge-bevel algorithm, and probably solving with some editing is inevitable.

This is how I would approach this in Blender, given my simple experience so far. I have created a simple demonstration case. Pictures would probably explain the approach better:
[image]

I would knife-cut the main face at least, although other connected faces might need the same too (as in my case)
[image]

I would then dissolve the faces that are attached to the target edge
[image]

and lastly apply the bevel and clean afterwards, if necessary
[image]

cheers and good luck,

Comment: Blender works best when working with quad based topology.

Comment: I was emulating conditions that the OP mentioned in his questions. Specifically, "subfaces", and "I have a polygon face with lots of "blender faces" in it", and the fact that the supplied image shows tri's. I tried with quads after trying the above, and the results were not any better. The built-in edge bevel in Blender has limitations, and sometimes has to be cleaned manually.